# Maximum number of elements that can be stored in an array in c

Tags: c, arrays, string

Please pardon me if it is a copy question. I will be happy to delete it if pointed out.

The question is that, if I declare a character array in c, say

```
char character_array[4];
```

Does that mean I can only store 3 characters and one '/0' is added as the fourth character? But I have tried it and successfully added four characters into the character array. But when I do that where is the '/0' added since I have already used up the four positions?

Comment: C doesn't really have strings. If you don't put the 0 in "manually" the string will be unterminated, and will have unpredictable effects if you try to print it out.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean C *does* have strings, it just doesn't have an explicit string *type*. Something not ending with a 0 byte isn't considered a string.

Comment: Note it depends upon how you use the above character array. If you use it as a string, (like you apply string library functions to it ) then the null character is necessary but if it simply is character array (just a collection of characters ), the '\0' character is not needed.

Comment: No, it means you can store 4 `char`s. A `char []` is not a string! @MalcolmMcLean: Is correct, C does not have a string in the sense as other languages have. It is only a convention how to use a `char []`.

Comment: @Olaf: no, it's not correct to say "C doesn't have strings". It doesn't have a string type, but it *has* string literals, string handling functions and a definition of what a string is (*A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null
character.*). According to this definition, there's no such thing as an "unterminated string", it just wouldn't *be* a string.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Just because the functions are called "string" does not mean the C language has strings. String literals are syntactic sugar only for compound literals with `char` elements, resp. corresponding intialisers. So it is safe to start with "C has no strings" if it is elabrated afterwards like Malcolm and I did. The cited definition exactly describes the convention I mentioned. And I'm pretty sure I explcitly wrote "in the sense as other languages have", too. Maybe you want to read the whole text before commenting?

Comment: @Olaf it's a *definition* in the standard, not a convention. Enough said.

Comment: What I said was C doesn't _really_ have strings. Technically, strings are not first class objects, but that statement is only meaningful to someone who knows the jargon.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean: Well yes, but that's the correct way to put it (and I consider *doesn't have a string type* easier to understand for beginners). What is meant be "*really* having" something remains a bit vague ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, yes, you can store any four characters. The string-termination character `'\0'` is a character just like any other.

But you don't have to store strings, `char` is a small integer so you can do:

```
char character_array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

This uses all four elements, but doesn't store printable characters nor any termination; the result is not a C string.

If you want to store a string, you need to accommodate the terminator character of course, since C strings by definition always end with the termination character.

C does not have protection against buffer overflow, if you aim at your foot and pull the trigger it will, in general, happily blow it off for you. Some of us like this. :)

Comment: Thank you @unwind . Got it now..I have been wasting 4 hours because of this stupid error. They should give a warning I think. :-)

Comment: @Allen "They should give a warning I think" -->provided a chuckle.  In C, there is not much "they".  C is coding - [without a net](https://sparkfun.com/images/newsimages/tightrope.jpg).

Answer (score 2):

You mix two notions: the notion of arrays and the notion of strings.

In this declaration

```
char character_array[4];
```

there is declared an array that can store 4 objects of type `char`. It is not important what values the objects will have.

On the other hand the array can contain a string: a sequence of characters limited with a terminating zero.

For example you can initialize the array above in C the following way

```
char character_array[4] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' };
```

or

```
char character_array[4] = "ABCD";
```

or

```
char character_array[4] = { '\0' };
```

or

```
char character_array[4] = "";
```

and so on.

In all these cases the array has 4 objects of type `char`. In the last two cases you may suppose that the array contains strings (empty strings) because the array has an element with zero character ( `'\0'` ). That is in the last two cases you may apply to the array functions that deal with strings.

Or another example

```
char character_array[4] = { 'A', 'B', '\0', 'C' };
```

You can deal with the array as if it had a string `"AB"` or just four objects.

Consider this demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char character_array[4] = { 'A', 'B', '\0', 'C' };

    char *p = strchr(character_array, 'C');

    if (p == NULL)
    {
        printf("Character '%c' is not found in the array\n", 'C');
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Character '%c' is found in the array at position %zu\n",
            'C',
            (size_t)(p - character_array));
    }

    p = ( char * )memchr(character_array, 'C', sizeof(character_array));

    if (p == NULL)
    {
        printf("Character '%c' is not found in the array\n", 'C');
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Character '%c' is found in the array at position %zu\n",
            'C',
            (size_t)(p - character_array));
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
Character 'C' is not found in the array
Character 'C' is found in the array at position 3
```

In the first part of the program it is assumed that the array contains a string. The standard string function `strchr` just ignores all elements of the array after encountering the element with the value `'\0'`.

In the second part of the program it is assumed that the array contains a sequence of objects with the length of 4. The standard function `memchr` knows nothing about strings.

Conclusion.

This array

```
char character_array[4];
```

can contain 4 objects of type character. It is so declared.

The array can contain a string if to interpret its content as a string provided that at least one element of the array is equal to `'\0'`.

For example if to declare the array like

```
char character_array[4] = "A";
```

that is equivalent to

```
char character_array[4] = { 'A', '\0', '\0', '\0' };
```

then it may be said that the array contains the string "A" with the length equal to 1. On the other hand the array actually contain 4 object of type `char` as the second equivalent declaration shows.

Answer (score 0):

You just reserve 4 bytes to fill with. If you write to _array[4] (the fifth character) you have a so called buffer overflow, means you write to non-reserved memory.

If you store a string in 4 characters, you have actually just 3 characters for printable characters (_array[0], ..., _array[2]) and the last one (_array[3]) is just for keeping the string termination '\0'.

For instance, in your case the function strlen() parses until such string termination '\0' and returns length=3.